# Symfony access assets folder

Tags: symfony, assets

I have some folders in www/web/ which is the root.
It's the following folder: assets/exports/
And it contains a file export.xsl

When I do in javascript:

```
window.open('/assets/exports/export.xsl');
```

I'm going to the following link:
http://mywebsite/assets/exports/export.xsl

But I get a: 404 not found

Is symfony somehow protecting this link?
So, my question is, how can I access this file, so it starts downloading for the visitor?

Answer (score 1):

From [Symfony Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html):

> Keep in mind that web/ is a public directory and that anything stored here will be publicly accessible, including all the original asset files (e.g. Sass, LESS and CoffeeScript files).

Make sure you put the files in a proper directory: `<symfony_root_dir>/web`. See below.

[image]

Then accessing the http://mywebsite/assets/exports/export.xsl returns the file's content.

Check also your server configuration, virtual host config and read [web server configuration guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html) from Symfony to see if you configured it properly.